# JSON.stringify(array) surrounded with square brackets

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sqlite, stringify

I'm trying to get an array of data to insert into multiple columns in an sqlite database, I'v got it almost working with this:

```
function InsertData(dbData){
  var valueArray = [], dataArray = [];
  var values = Object.keys(dbData);
  for(var key in values){
    valueArray[valueArray.length] = values[key];
    dataArray[dataArray.length] = dbData[values[key]];
  }
  console.log("INSERT INTO "+dbData.table+" ("+valueArray+") VALUES ("+JSON.stringify(dataArray)+")");
  dbData.database.serialize(function(){
    dbData.database.run("INSERT INTO "+dbData.table+" ("+valueArray+") VALUES ("+JSON.stringify(dataArray)+")");
  });
}
```

My data is constructed as so:

```
//app.js
function EventData(title, value, other){
  this.title = title;
  this.value = value;
  this.other = other;
}
EventData.prototype = new dbtools.DBData(usuevents, 'event');
var thisEventData = new EventData('newData', 4, 2);

//dbtools.js
DBData = function(database, table){
  this.database = database;
  this.table = table;
};
```

the console.log outputs **INSERT INTO event (title,value,other) VALUES (["newData",4,2])**
I just need the [] square brackets removed on **(["newData",4,2])**.
How would I do this? Also if there is a better way to insert data into sqlite im open to suggestions. Thanks

Comment: JSON is not SQL.  You need to use parameters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(dataArray)` will always return square brackets because `dataArray` is of type array. Instead, you could stringify each element of your array, then join them separated by commas.

```
dataArray = dataArray.map(function(e){
  return JSON.stringify(e);
});

dataString = dataArray.join(",");
```

Then

```
["newData",4,2]
```

becomes

```
"newData",4,2
```

**Addendum:** Please don't try to `replace()` out the brackets manually because it could be that one day a bracket enters your array in a string. e.g. `["Please see ref[1]",4,2]`

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Drakes and S McCrohan for your answers. I found that `.replace(/]|[[]/g, '')` appended to `JSON.stringify(dataArray)`

full line `JSON.stringify(dataArray).replace(/]|[[]/g, '')`

Comment: It could be possible that at some point in the future a bracket could creep into one of your `dataArray` entries. It's been known to happen

Comment: Right. If you want to take the regex approach (which is also valid), try `/^\[|]$/g`, to only match at the beginning and end of the string and avoid altering any interior elements.

Answer (score 5):

Drake's answer would be my personal choice, because the code clearly expresses the intent. But to show an alternative:

```
var strung = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
console.log(strung.substring(1,strung.length-1));
```